# Form implementation with Bootstrap

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I would like to have a form designed like the image below:
[image]

I tried with the following code:

```
<form>

          <div class="form-group form-inline">
            <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Navn:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="" data-required="true" name="navn">
          </div>

          <div class="form-group form-inline">
            <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Bedrift:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="" data-required="true" name="bedrift">
          </div>


          <div class="form-group form-inline">
            <label for="exampleInputPassword1" class>Tlf:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="" data-required="true" name="tlf">
          </div>

          <div class="form-group form-inline">
            <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Mailadresse:</label>
            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="" data-required="true" name="mailadresse">
          </div>

          <input id="input-region" type="hidden" name="region" value="">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Send</button>
        </form>
```

But the result is not what I expected.

I do I put the labels and the input on a white box without using the label as a placeholder.

Comment: Why is the result not what you expected?

Comment: Bootstrap doesn't have any components that do what you want by itself. You need to override the css and/or modify the HTML with your own code. Probably should give `form-group` a white background and remove border on the `form-control` elements.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use the placeholder feature, i guess?

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<form>

          <div class="form-group form-inline">
            <label for="exampleInputPassword1" class="sr-only">Navn:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Navn:" data-required="true" name="navn">
          </div>

          <div class="form-group form-inline">
            <label for="exampleInputPassword1" class="sr-only">Bedrift:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Bedrift:" data-required="true" name="bedrift">
          </div>


          <div class="form-group form-inline">
            <label for="exampleInputPassword1" class="sr-only"></label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Tlf:" data-required="true" name="tlf">
          </div>

          <div class="form-group form-inline">
            <label for="exampleInputEmail1" class="sr-only"></label>
            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Mailadresse:" data-required="true" name="mailadresse">
          </div>

          <input id="input-region" type="hidden" name="region" value="">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Send</button>
        </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of place holder feature

check this snippet

```css
body {
  background: blue;
}
input {
  margin: 5px;
  margin-left: 20px;
}
form {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 500px;
}
button {
  align-self:center;
  width:100px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<form>

  <div class="form-group form-inline">

    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Navn:" data-required="true" name="navn">
  </div>

  <div class="form-group form-inline">

    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Bedrift:" data-required="true" name="bedrift">
  </div>


  <div class="form-group form-inline">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Tlf:" data-required="true" name="tlf">
  </div>

  <div class="form-group form-inline">

    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Mailadresse" data-required="true" name="mailadresse">
  </div>

  <input id="input-region" type="hidden" name="region" value="">
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Send</button>
</form>
```

Hope this helps